# Can't select multi-select items. Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have implemented the following multiselect into my project.
http://loudev.com/

And I have done everything as I should (as far as I know) the layout is looking as it should, the css and javascript is running but when i hover over an option, it isn't clickable, it treats it as a line of  text, not a clickable object.

Here is the code for the select input and where it is initialised in javascript.

```html
<select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" id="my-select" name="my-select[]">
  <option value="elem_1">elem 1</option>
  <option value="elem_2">elem 2</option>
  <option value="elem_3">elem 3</option>
  <option value="elem_4">elem 4</option>
  <option value="elem_100">elem 100</option>
</select>
```

```js
$('#my-select').multiSelect();
```

Comment: Check the console for errors. It's likely you've missed a JS file reference, or have them in the wrong order.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Nope no errors, I also thought the `class="form-control"` might have clashed with something so I removed it and it had no impact. I have referenced the only js file that came with it

Comment: In that case are you running the jQuery code after the DOM has loaded? Either in a document.ready handler, or in a script block just before `</body>`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan at the bottom of the body just before the ``</body>` tag

Comment: Can you provide a CDN link to multiselect? And which version of jquery?

Comment: I note that the example on `http://loudev.com/#usage` doesn't actually include jquery, yet immediately uses jquery in the example.

Comment: @freedomn-m I don't use a CDN for the multiselct, only jquery itself. I get the javascript code from a js file i had to put into my project

Comment: No worries - found one - using jquery 3.3.1 (latest on  SO) and 0.9.12 multiselect, it appears to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/by8v0u45/  So there must be an issue with how you've set up your page (or different versions).  Could be one or most *other* styles (eg `select.form-control` (bootstrap?)) are causing conflicts.  Try with a very simple page using *just* jquery+multiselect (no other scripts/includes) - if it works there then it's a matter of finding the conflict (**edit** I see you've already tried that)

Comment: @freedomn-m Ah the new one that you put in jsfiddle seems to be making progress, i can click on the items, but they dont move over to the next panel.

Comment: on http://loudev.com/ using firefox items moves to next panel and viceversa